# Merging local branch into modified original branch

Tags: java, git, github, merge, version-control

I have forked original repository into my github account and cloned the same into my workspace. After working for a week on my local branch I want to push my local branch to my forked repository and then merge it with original repository. But I can see that files that I have modified in my local branch have also been modified in the original repository. I can think of two approaches for merging my local branch safely.

1. Should I first get the latest changes from the original repository into my local branch using `git pull`? In this case will the complete file be overridden or only parts of the file that has changed in the original repository preserving my local changes.
2. Second approach is to go ahead with pushing my changes to my forked repository and then merge it with original repository. Here I am assuming that `Git` considers a conflict only if there are two different versions of the same line in a file. In case the two versions of the file have changes in different parts of the file they can be merged safely.

I am also little unclear about when `Git` merges two versions of a file. How does it decide which version of the file will take precedence over the other.

Any other approach to do the same is welcome.

Comment: You're looking at potential conflicts no matter what you do.  You could push and then issue a pull request back to the parent branch, but GitHub won't allow it to complete if there are merge conflicts.  You could also `git pull`, but then you also might get conflicts.  Git is cautious and most of the time won't assume which version to use unless it is reasonably clear what to do.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen but isn't this a very common scenario where files do get modified in parent branch while we work on a child branch. And expect git to handle this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, in such scenario it is hard to avoid conflicts at all, and generally working on the same repository with other people you should be prepared to resolve conflicts once in a while.

In your case I would use `git rebase` and utilize git branches, which are a really useful feature when used well.

1. Create separate branch with your changes locally
2. Revert your local **master** branch to the state before this changes
3. Update local **master** branch with changes from the original repository
4. Push your **master** branch to your remote repository (so that your forked version matches the original repository)
5. **Rebase** your local feature branch onto master. In this step you'll probably need to resolve some conflicts. But it would be easier, as you are based on current master (destination of your changes), and you are in control what should go in, and what should not. Also, you can easily test your solution after rebase, and make some changes before issueing a pull request.
6. Push local feature branch with your changes to your remote repository.
7. Create pull request to the original repository.

   ```
   // I assume that your local master branch is set up to track origin/master branch, where origin is your forked version of the original repository. 
   // 1. Local branch named "my-new-feature"
   $ git branch my-new-feature
   // 2. Reset your master branch back to the state before changes
   $ git fetch origin
   $ git reset --hard origin/master
   // 3. Update local master branch. First you need to add the original repository as a remote (let's name it "upstream") 
   $ git remote add upstream https://github.com/some-user/some-project.git
   $ git fetch upstream
   // you should still be on your local master branch. Now update this local branch with changes from the original repo
   $ git rebase upstream/master
   // 4. Push your local master to your forked repository
   $ git push origin master
   // 5. Rebase your changes onto master
   $ git checkout my-new-feature
   $ git rebase master
   // This is the place where you are most likely to have conficts. Read git messages, as it helps you what to do. 
   // Once all conflicts have been resolved, stage your changes but do not commit. If committed they will not be detected by ongoing rebase.  
   $ git add .
   $ git rebase --continue
   // 6. Push your local branch with newest changes
   $ git push origin my-new-feature
   // 7. Issue a pull request on GitHub using your just pushed branch
   ```

Also, `git` merges two files based on the direction of the merge. If you are on a branch A-branch, and you run `git merge B-branch`, then files from **B-branch** have "higher priority" and their changes will be most likely applied automatically.

Answer (score 0):

I will suggest the first approch as you listed: **pull the changes from the original repo firs**t. Reasons as below:

1. It will save energies for the users who view pull request and merge the branches.
2. If there has conflicts for mering the pull request, you should also resolve the conflicts again in your local repo, and then push to the fork repo again.
3. Pull changes from the original repo only overwrite parts of files not all files. Situations as below:

   - **Files neither changed in original repo nor your local repo:** these files won’t changed.
   - **Files changed in the original repo but not changed in your local repo:** these files will be overwrited as the version of the original repo in your local repo.
   - **Files not changed in original repo but changed in your local repo:** these files won’t be overwrite.
   - **File both changed in original repo and in your local repo:** these files will show as conflicts, you should resolve the conflicts manually.

To pull the changes from original repo, you’d better pull with `--rebase` option (pull the change from original repo first, then apply your local changes on the top of the latest original repo:

```
git pull <remote> <branch> --rebase
```

Assume the commit histroy as below after `git fetch` (`origin` is the remote for the fork repo, `upstream` is the remote for the original repo):

```
…---A---B---C---D---E  master, origin/master
         \
           F---G---H  upstream/master
```

Then you can execute below commands:

```
git pull upstream master --rebase 
git push origin master -f
```

Then the commit history will be:

```
…---A---B---F---G---H---C'---D'---F'  master, origin/master
                    |
              upstream/master
```

Then you can create a PR to merge the fork repo `master` branch into the original repo. It will be convenient for PR viewers and approvers.